# Native Android JAVA to Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console

I have a native app. I write it on JAVA. My apps is shared on google play store so,  if i going to write my app again with flutter and i give same package_name this new flutter app. Can i update my app or i musn't change it to flutter ?

Comment: A most detailed answer can be found in [this another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65428687/6248208).

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade as long as it is signed with the same key and has a larger version number than your native app. Do not forget to keep compatibility with the file system of your current app, since if you use a database, for example, it should be accessed in the same way in your Flutter app.

To be sure, try an upgrade by uploading an alpha version of Google Play and upgrading to your own device.