# Can a new Android app replace existing app in the play store?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I have an android app developed in native Android, which is released in the Play store. I am wondering if I should rebuild the app in Flutter as I want both Android and iOS apps. However, I am not sure if the new android app developed using Flutter will be able to replace the current app. I want to use the same package name and release key. Also, most importantly preserve my users.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Update a flutter app on already published native android using java app in play console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64005603/how-to-update-a-flutter-app-on-already-published-native-android-using-java-app-i)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible if you sign the new flutter app with the same release key and with the same package id.

Comment: That is fantastic. Thank you!

Comment: What about existing database and login details

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can replace already existing app with Flutter app but you need to take care of few points to be able to do this.
Please take care of following things:

1. The package name must be identical with the old application. Please take a look into Manifest file of old app and replace the package name in new application AndroidManifest.xml file with the package name from old application.
2. Now take care of the versionCode and versionName, this info can be retrieved from AndroidManifest file of old application and upgrade it in  Flutter's pubspec.yaml file with version attribute as it is must to keep it greater than previously released application. This attribute has the form of 0.1.1+3 where 0.1.1 corresponds to versionName and 3 (the number after + sign) to versionCode.
3. Here's the crucial part, the keystore file used to sign New Flutter's version must be the same used to sign the Android's native release.

If you follow all these steps then you can update the new version of the application irrespective of the programming framework you are using i.e  Kotlin, Flutter, React Native or any other technology.

Answer (score 1):

That should indeed be possible. Afaik a play store "update" is just a new apk. I have had plenty of apps that have done this, so it is definitely possible, you'll just want to make sure package names and other important config objects are the same.

Comment: That is fantastic. Thank you!

Comment: What about existing database versions and updates?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can do that. You just need to take care of Package name, Version name and Version code of you application (if applicable).