# Replace Xamarin App with Native on play store

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play

we have a xamarin(forms) app and we are working on convert it yo native Android and IOS,

My question is if we keep the same package name and signature can we upload to google play to replace the xamarin?

and will the user be able to update the app?

i seen many NO, since the structure of Xamarin is different then Native

Database is not the same, like we are using Room.

im almost sure its not possible but just need to confirm.

thx

Comment: Every time you update any app the new version overwrite the old one if the app id and signature are the same.  Whether or not the new version can read all the data from the old version is up to you

Comment: i never heard of xamarin to native updates do..i guess il make a test app and try.thx

Comment: Technology doesn't matter for updates. The only problem could be local data but for that we would need to know what you save localy.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64005603/how-to-update-a-flutter-app-on-already-published-native-android-using-java-app-i/64005706#64005706